# Database application. Adding data to a logged in user only visible to the user logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I am creating a simple web application that allows a logged user to store data not shared with other users.

I am having trouble associating the data to the user.

The model looks like this:

```
namespace TvShowsDb.Models
{
    public class TvShow
    {
        public int TvShowID { get; set; }
        public string TvShowName { get; set; }
        public string LastEpisodeSeen { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public bool SeenAll { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateLastEdited { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And the generated user model from ASP.NET MVC5 looks like this with my additions:

```
namespace TvShowsDb.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public IList<TvShow> TvShows { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TvShowsDb.Models.TvShow> TvShows { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when a logged in user goes to the create tv show web page and creates a tvshow then that specific tv show and the data from the model gets added to the user. I have a list in the user with tv shows.

Here is a picture of how the database looks: 
[image: Database look]

Here is the code for when I add a tvshow:

```
    // POST: TvShows/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TvShowID,TvShowName,LastEpisodeSeen,Comment,SeenAll,DateAdded,DateLastEdited")] TvShow tvShow)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            IList<TvShow> tvshows = user.TvShows;
            user.TvShows.Add(tvShow);
           // db.TvShows.Add(tvShow);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(tvShow);
    }
```

I get the user, that works and returns the correct user. Then I get the tv show list, that returns null. Then the adding fails since the tvshow list is null.

How do I go about adding tvshows to the user so that I can show them on the index page for that particular user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing the users table directly and including the child collection:

```
var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = db.Users.Include(u => u.TvShows).Single(u => u.Id == id);
```

Comment: That gives me an error on that line:  "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Define the user before the query - `var ID = User.Identity.GetUserId(); var user = db.Users.Include(u => u.TvShows).Single(u => u.Id == ID);`

Comment: Stephen, yes that works. I would love an explanation of why that works. Also, is this the standard way of accessing the user and his data?
If Steve updates his answer to include Stephens change then I will mark that as the correct answer. If Stephen makes an answer with his comment then I will mark that as the accepted answer.
Thanks guys.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Basically LINQ to entities can't make a SQL statement out of that. Another way of handling that part is to use AsEnumerable() after the LINQ to Entity part and then continue with LINQ to Objects after that. As for whether .Include() is the standard way, well it's one way. You could also do a projection with .Select(u => new {...}) and access the children in there to flatten them out or otherwise transform it. Include() gives you access to the child(ren), but be careful with multiple includes and performance.